# How to store html values through sequelize ORM in nodeJS application?

Tags: node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I am working on one NodeJs application with NodeJS, Sequelize ORM and mysql2 database.

I am creating a model xyz with one field called "text" which should hold HTML values from frontend as its getting values from a text editor in frontend with bold or italic functionalities among many.

What datatype should I assign to this field "text" in Sequelize as I am lost and I searched but could not find.

I think we cannot store that in String.

Cany anyone suggest ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LONGTEXT` is probably excessive -- it allows data sizes up to 4GB.

`MEDIUMTEXT` allows 16MB.

`TEXT` allows 64KB.

`TINYTEXT` allows only 255 characters.

Very few HTML documents are going to be 64KB in size, so a `TEXT` ought to be suitable for you. If you really want to be safe, go for a `MEDIUMTEXT`.

Use [TEXT](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/data-types.js%7ETEXT.html) datatype for sequelize